# Creating a Panel of JButtons with values from a SQL table;

Tags: java, mysql

What I am trying to do is get the values from a column in my SQL table, specifically a column named SubjectName. Once I have these values I want to create JButtons named for each value in the ResultSet.  My current code connects to my database and as far as I can tell the query to the table also works, however when I attempt to generate and add these buttons to my display the try/catch only returns that my statement failed.  The code causing the problem lies somewhere here:

```
try
    (
        Statement initializeDisplay = connect.createStatement()
    ){

    ArrayList<String> buttonList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = initializeDisplay.executeQuery("SELECT SubjectName from subjectpacktable order by SubjectID");
        buttonList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            buttonList.add(rs.getString(1));
        }

        ArrayList<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            String temp2 = rs.getString(l);
            JButton button1 = new JButton(temp2);
            listOfButtons.add(button1);
            l++;
        }
        l = 0;
        while(listOfButtons.get(l) != null)
        {
            JButton tempButton = listOfButtons.get(l);
            AddCardPanel1.add(tempButton);
            l++;
        }
        while(buttonList.get(l) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(buttonList.get(l));
            l++;
        }
        l = 0;
    }
    catch(SQLException e1)
    {
        System.err.println("Initial Display Failed");
    }} catch (SQLException e2) 
    {
        System.err.println("Initial Display Failed");
    }
```

I'm wondering if the problem lies in actually retrieving the values from the table or somewhere else in the code are values not being assigned properly.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Recommendation Number 1: Improve those catch blocks so they tell you something useful. At least print the stacktrace. i.e., `e1.printStackTrace();` and likewise for e2, `e2.printStackTrace();`

Comment: After you iterate over your resultSet inside the while, you try to retrieve data from the resultSet in this command: 
    `String temp2 = rs.getString(l);`
This is probably a source of error.

Comment: @Dalton How would you recommend remedying this issue?  I went back and attempted to take the values from the resultSet and place those directly into the list of buttons, however, the errors still persist.  Is it possible the values in resultSet aren't being retrieved properly?

Comment: Please, use @Hovercraft Full Of Eels recommendation, grab the error and update your answer. Then we can see the error more cleary.

Comment: @Dalton I followed HovercraftFullOfEels recommendation and I added in the printStackTrace() in the catch blocks as recommended and the error I get in return is a SQLException: Column index out of range, 0 < 1.  I'm not sure what is causing this, whether its my SQL Query or somewhere in the while loops that this occurs.

Comment: By the error you're reporting, I assume that the variable l = 0 before you call `String temp2 = rs.getString(l);`. Change l to 1 `l = 1` or make it in the code, `String temp2 = rs.getString(1);`. Another safe you to retrieve the data is `String temp2 = rs.getString("SubjectName");`. The reason for your error is that resultSet.getString can only receive int greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the while loop, do

```
for(int i=0;i<buttonList.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(listOfButtons.get(i).getText());
}
```

this should keep your index inside the array bounds

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! I used @Dalton and @BartHofma's reccommendations and got the code up and running.

Here is the working code:

```
try
    (
        Statement initializeDisplay = connect.createStatement();
    )
    {

    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = initializeDisplay.executeQuery("SELECT SubjectName from subjectpacktable order by SubjectID");

        ArrayList<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String temp2 = rs.getString("SubjectName");
            JButton button1 = new JButton(temp2);
            listOfButtons.add(button1);
            l++;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<listOfButtons.size();i++)
        {
            JButton holderButton = listOfButtons.get(i);
            final String SubjectString = listOfButtons.get(i).getText();
            holderButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {

                    try 
                    {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    }
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) 
                        {
                            System.err.println("Connection Failed");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Driver Connected");

                    Connection connect = null;
                    try 
                    {
                        connect = DriverManager.getConnection
                                ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example","root","root1229");
                    } 
                        catch (SQLException e1)
                        {
                            System.err.println("Connection Failed");
                        }
                    System.out.println("Database Connected");

                    String addCardStatement;
                    k++;
                    int cardID = 0;
                    cardID += k;
                    String cardFront;
                    String cardBack;
                    cardFront = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to name the card?");
                    cardBack = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to define the card as?");
                    addCardStatement = "INSERT INTO " + SubjectString + "VALUES (" + cardID + "," + SubjectString + "," + cardFront + "," + cardBack + ")";
                    try 
                    {
                        Statement addStatement = connect.createStatement();
                        addStatement.executeUpdate(addCardStatement);
                    } 
                        catch (SQLException e1) 
                        {
                            System.err.println("Statement failed");
                        }


                }});

            AddCardPanel1.add(holderButton);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e1)
    {
        System.err.println("Initial Display Failed");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }} catch (SQLException e2) 
    {
        System.err.println("Initial Display Failed");
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```